# "Baby" without article

Tags: articles

In articles I often read the author refer to a baby as "baby", without an article. Example:

> She insists there is no modern proof that it is safe for baby

Our midwife does the same, always referring to "baby".

> When baby does this

I'm not a native speaker English speaker and that's contrary to my intuition which is to say "the baby" so I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Just curious, but what is your native language? French, Spanish...?

Comment: @Cascabel German

Comment: Thank you, yes, my question was a duplicate, sorry about that. Thanks for pointing me to explanations.

Comment: Compare "The ideal Christmas present for Mum!" (not "your mother"). The writer is 'speaking' as though they were a member of your family.